# using "if" - when to use present tense, and when to use past tense?

Tags: tenses, past-tense, conditionals, present-tense, clauses

As a native speaker of English, these two sentences sound acceptable to me:

> A full refund *can* be claimed if the school *fails* to provide a
>   textbook.
>
> A full refund *could* be claimed if the school *failed* to provide a
>   textbook.

But is it not the case that there are situations where both present and past tense *cannot* be used interchangeably when using "if' to create a conditional clause?

Comment: *When I went to school, full marks **could** be obtained if the pupil **answered** every exam question correctly.* You can't recast that sentence using present tense *can, answers*.

Answer (score -2):

Could is the past tense of can as it is in may/might, will/would. 
Using a particular form (past or present) must be adhered to.

Comment: Could I beg to differ? May I beg to differ? Would I beg to differ? Yes I can, yes I might, yes I will. No past tense.